# Can I launch the `GetLastError` in the first row of my function?

Tags: c++, winapi

I know the `GetLastError` are to be called at once when error occured. I wrote the function:

```
void PrintErrorMsg() {
    DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
    LPTSTR msg = NULL;
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, errCode, 0, (LPTSTR)&msg, 0, NULL);
    wcerr << msg << endl;
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, msg);
}
```

Now I use it in my code:

```
LPCTSTR boundaryName = L"BushmanBoundary";
HANDLE hBoundary = CreateBoundaryDescriptor(boundaryName, 0);
if (NULL == hBoundary) {
    PrintErrorMsg();
}
```

So I called `GetLastError` in the first code row inside of the `PrintErrorMsg` function. Whether such variant of using is admissible?

Comment: As long as you don't call other Windows API functions that affect the error condition, then you should be ok.

Comment: I would provide the error code as a parameter to `PrintErrorMsg` and let the caller call `GetLastError` at the appropriate time. That makes it more obvious and safer that the no code "slips" in between the call you make and the `PrintErrorMsg()`.

Comment: Yes @Christian.K, I too. But *the behaviour* of the case without any parameters is interesting for me too.

Comment: @AndreyBushman Fair enough. You could have one `PrintLastErrorMsg` and one `PrintErrorMsg(DWORD errorCode)` to emphasize the difference then. But then I guess, that was not your question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Functions executed by the calling thread set this value by calling the SetLastError function. You should call the GetLastError function immediately when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data. That is because some functions call SetLastError with a zero when they succeed, wiping out the error code set by the most recently failed function.

Your code is fine because you are not calling a function that may call `SetLastError()` in between failure and your call to `GetLastError()` (e.g. Win32 API Calls.)

Keep in mind that the insertion operator may call `SetLastError()`.

```
std::cout << "Win32 function failed with error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
```

I've been caught out by something like this in the past where `GetLastError()` would not return the correct error code because it had been set/reset by the insertion operator.

Answer (score 2):

That code is fine. No Windows API functions are called between `CreateBoundaryDescriptor` returning, and your call to `GetLastError`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's allowed. I've done something similar, except that I pass the error code in as an argument, but make the default value for the argument the result of `GetLastError()`, like this:

```
// in header file
void PrintErrorMsg( DWORD errCode = GetLastError() );


// in implementation file
void PrintErrorMsg( DWORD errCode  )
{
   // ...
}
```

It's more flexible, and worked very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the best way to deal with these low-level details of the Win32 API (or any C style API), is to immediately hoist that C style API into C++ practices as soon as possible.  One approach I used was to wrap C-style API calls in a macro that validates the return value and then extracts the appropriate error code into an exception if the return value indicated failure.

[Chapter 1](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/book/download/01-Introduction.pdf) of my book ["The Direct3D Graphics Pipeline"](https://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/the-direct3d-graphics-pipeline/) outlines such an approach for COM `HRESULT` return values.  A macro `THR` throws if the `HRESULT` indicates failure.  In an `HRESULT`, the failure status and error code are contained in the same integral value, so the exception can be computed directly from the provided `HRESULT`.  The macro decorates its argument with `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` before passing the value to be checked onto a helper function that checks for failure.  If failure was detected, all the information is gathered up into an exception that is thrown.  If the `HRESULT` indicates success, the `HRESULT` value is returned.

I also provided similar variants for Win32 API status with `TWS`.  This does the necessary validation checks for the Win32 API (usually some version of comparing against `FALSE` or `0`) and on failure immediately calls `::GetLastError()` to obtain the error code for the exception.

In both cases, I attempt to use `::FormatMessage` to obtain a meaningful error message string when building the exception value that will be thrown.

These macros are intended to be used in situations where you don't expect the API call to fail and failure is indeed truly exceptional.